# Screen rotation shortcuts in login without editing files

Tags: gnome, 20.04, login-screen, shortcuts, display-rotation

I have a netbook that allows screen rotation. The problem is that it only will rotate sideways, and once it does, won't get horizontal again, no matter how I move the machine.

To add to the problem, the touchpad doesn't follow the rotation.

I tried different key combinations, but none work.

There are keyboard shortcuts that allow authomatic screen rotation, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>?

I can edit files to change the rotation configuration, but it seems to me that it shouldn't be necessary, since I get stuck in a screen that is very difficult to interact with.

Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
xrandr -o normal
```